# Visual Studio alternative with very specific requirements

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ide

I couldn't find an alternative to Visual Studio that is lightweight, as in requiring: <500mb of disk space, ~256mb of memory, ~1.6Ghz CPU, has autocomplete, works under XP, doesn't require to install 25 additional tools to work, is for C++, is free.

Is there such an alternative? This old machine of mine can't handle anything better...

Comment: CodeBlocks works well for me.

Comment: Is it enough for you to use online C++ compilers? There are many of them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916000/online-c-compiler-and-evaluator

Comment: I've read that Codeblocks requires 512-1024mb of memory, which is way too much for me. As for online compilers - I don't think they are fit for bigger projects, which is what I've.

Comment: @Jack, Mine is a bit over 600MB with a crapload of extra stuff in it. If you're not counting boost as part of CodeBlocks, that alone is 90MB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My favorite is [CodeLite](http://www.codelite.org/) - [[screenshot](http://www.codelite.org/images/editor_general.png)] - small, fast, stable, standard compliant (using gcc).

With regard to question about disk and memory consumption here's some data from my machine:

Memory usage (a small project with 7 classes):

- Private bytes: 32211 KB
- Working set:   54292 KB

There is also an indexer process:

- Private bytes: 1488 KB
- Working set:   4520 KB

Disk usage:

- MinGW: ~130 MB
- CodeLite: ~70 MB

Comment: Never heard of it, I can't find system requirements. How much space does it take and how much memory does it use?

Comment: Thank you, this is what I'm going with.

Answer (score 1):

How about http://www.bloodshed.net/devcpp.html? It is not VS, but it lightweighted as far as I remember.

Comment: Indeed it does seem lightweight. I haven't seen this as a requirement, and it seems that it's low on features, including smart autocomplete option. If nothing better comes up by the end of the day, I'll have to use it though.

Comment: its a light IDE, but its prone to crashes at the worst times (which it occasionally recovers from) and worst of all, its compiler is archaic, GCC 3.4.x IIRC, if you do go down this road, you need to totally replace the mingw it uses.